# Have a single program run in Debian

Tags: debian, startup, application

I am a chiptune musician and I've been fascinated with different trackers and ways to make music. Currently I have been interested in starting to use a tracker called LittleGPTracker, which can run on a variety of systems, but I would like to run it on a modded Pi with Debian (the hardware side is taken care of).

I would like to have Debian startup like a gameboy, in the sense that it *immediately* after start up, will load the program and *only* use that program. I know the startup is a tad long for the Pi in this sense but I would like to have a way to access the program faster than constantly having to find it and opening it up before a live set or something like that.

Comment: you might consider posting this question at [the rpi stackexchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'll copy paste the post to there as well!

Comment: @Octopus, I don't think so, this is not RPi specific but purely Debian. Even the Raspbian port of Debian for the RPi is 99.9% the same as Debian and the startup/login procedure is the same. What the OP is looking for is a hack that automatically logs a user in without a password and presents the X desktop and then starts the app.

Comment: then nevermind haha

Answer (score 0):

**Auto Login:**

In Terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/inittab`

Scroll down to:

`1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1`

and change to

`#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1`

Under that line add:

`1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1`

(where pi is the username you want to login).

Ctrl+X to exit, Y to save followed by enter twice

**Auto StartX (Run LXDE):**

In Terminal:

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Scroll to the bottom and add the following above exit 0:

`su -l pi -c startx`

(where pi is the username you want to run X as).

**Auto-starting an X app**

Next, edit the autostart file:

`sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

After the last line add a line for each application you wish to autorun. For example if I add lines for LXTerminal and Leafpad my file looks like this:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@xscreensaver -no-splash@
@lxterminal
@leafpad
```

*Not fully tested but this is the gist of it.*